# How to Set innerText By ElementHandle with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to set the `innerText` of an HTML element in a Puppeteer test environment and cannot (easily) get the element by CSS selector, so I'm getting the `elementHandle` via:

```
let [ el ] = await page.$x(`//span[contains(text(), 'addTestFile.pdf')]`)
```

I normally set `innerText` for testing purposes using `evaluate`, but I need a selector for that, e.g.:

```
await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('mySelector').innerText = '⚠️DOM modified for testing purposes⚠️')
```

Can I set `innerText` of a given `elementHandle` without a CSS selector?

I see I can get the value with `await el.getProperty('innerHTML')` but I'm not finding a way to set it.

Comment: Would something like, `const targetEle = [...document.querySelectorAll("span")].find(ele => ele.innerText.includes("addTestFile.pdf"))` to select your target element be helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out: I can use `evaluate` on the `elementHandle` as so:

```
let [ el ] = await page.$x(`//span[contains(text(), 'addTestFile.pdf')]`)
await el.evaluate(element => element.innerText = '⚠️DOM modified for testing purposes⚠️')
```